# JQuery and radio buttons in ASP.NET. Click is not registred

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I am trying to make my radio button switch off/on with jQuery but I am stuck with a problem that my radio button misses the clicks. I click on it and sometimes it changes its checked value and sometimes not. Actually I have found that in IE it works better than in Firefox (which allows me change it only once)

I use master page and radio button is on my content page. Here is the code which I have placed right behind `<asp:Content ...>` . I also do use Bootstrap CSS my jQuery version is 1.10.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //set radio button ON
        $("#<%=statusActive.ClientID%>").prop("checked", true); 

            //Assign click event to this specific radio button
            $("#<%=statusActive.ClientID%>").click(function () {

                //Get actual value of checked property and store it into local variable      
                var s = $("#<%=statusActive.ClientID%>").prop("checked");

                //If it was true set it to false and vice versa
                $("#<%=statusActive.ClientID%>").prop("checked", !s);

                //Tell me what value did you set
                $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val(!s);

            });

        });
</script>
```

**My HTML code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MainContent_statusActive").prop("checked", true);

            $("#MainContent_statusActive").click(function () {
                var s = $("#MainContent_statusActive").prop("checked");
                $("#MainContent_statusActive").prop("checked", !s);
                $("#MainContent_txtName").val(!s);
            });
...
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtName" type="text" id="MainContent_txtName" class="form-control" />
<span class="radio-inline"><input id="MainContent_statusActive" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$statusActive" value="statusActive" /><label for="MainContent_statusActive">Active</label></span>
```

Do you have idea what should be incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ***RadioButton*** like ***CheckBox***. If you want to use RadioButton for ***true/false*** value, you want to use two. Otherwise, I would like to suggest you to use ***CheckBox***.

[image]

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="ActiveRadioButton" runat="server" GroupName="Status" Text="Active" />        
<asp:RadioButton ID="InactiveRadioButton" runat="server" GroupName="Status" Text="Inactive" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="StatusCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Status" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //set radio button ON
        $("#<%=ActiveRadioButton.ClientID%>").prop("checked", true);                
        $("#<%=ActiveRadioButton.ClientID%>,#<%=InactiveRadioButton.ClientID%>").click(function () {                   

            var active = $('#<%= ActiveRadioButton.ClientID %>').is(":checked");
            var inactive = $('#<%= InactiveRadioButton.ClientID %>').is(":checked");

            console.log("active: " + active + ", inactive: " + inactive);
        });


        $("#<%=StatusCheckBox.ClientID%>").click(function () {

            var value = $('#<%= StatusCheckBox.ClientID %>').is(":checked");
            console.log("checkbox value: " + value);
        });

    });
</script>
```